# Optimization using Generalized Newton-Rhapson or Derivative Matching to Beta

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

I'm performing a numerical optimization of a function whose value I know and whose derivatives I can calculate. Let's say, for argument, that I'm optimizing the following function:

$$argmax_f: \sum_i log(\binom{N_i}{k_i} k_i^\theta N_i^{1-\theta})$$

Where: $$\theta = \frac{f}{f+(1-f)e^{\lambda_i}}$$

We can compute the gradient and hessian for this problem:

$$g = \sum_i \frac{k_i}{f} - \frac{N_i-k_i}{1-f} - \frac{N_i(1-e^{\lambda_i})}{f+(1-f)e^{\lambda_i}}$$

$$h = \sum_i -\frac{k_i}{f^2} - \frac{N_i - k_i}{(1-f)^2} + \frac{N_i(1-e^{\lambda_i})^2}{(f+(1-f)e^{\lambda_i})^2}$$

Using the ability to calculate derivatives and function values, what are some approaches for optimizing our value of $f$?

Specifically, a coworker mentioned something he referred to as Generalized Newton-Rhapson (sic?), whereby we match our derivatives to a function whose maximum we can compute in closed form. For instance, we would match the gradient and the hessian to those of a beta distribution, maximize the beta distribution, and repeat until convergence. Is this truly Generalized Newton-Rhapson, or is this approach named something different? Also, how do you match the derivatives to those of a beta distribution?

Any answers regarding these questions or any other optimization suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: First part: Take a look at the Wikipedia article on Newton Raphson. It is quite complete.
Second part: Why should the process converge?  Wouldn't that require that the initial function is already in the space spanned by your closed-form computable family?

Comment: The Generalized Newton-Rhapson (sic?) may suffer from numerical issues regarding the optimum as with any optimization procedure, but the reason we use the beta function is that _f_ is strictly in [0,1], as this is a binomial family function @g g.

Comment: I'm confident that your coworker was referring to the well-known Newton-Raphson method, not Newton-Rhapson.